# A few things I don't understand about inheritance

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, object, ecmascript-6

## I have created such a table on "inheritance".

1. compare ---prototype---> Animal.prototype(constructor,run)
2. Rabbit ---[[prototype]]---> compare
3. Rabbit ---prototype---> Animal
4. Rabbit.prototype ---[[prototype]]---> Animal.prototype(constructor,run)
5. rabbit(name:'White Rabbit') ---[[prototype]]---> Rabbit.prototype
6. rabbit(name:'White Rabbit') ---prototype---> Rabbit

.

- think they are true. But specify if there is a wrong. I wrote certain codes to understand the subject of 'inheritance'. But a few did not give the result I wanted. But a few did not give the result I wanted. ( Specification in comment lines )

```
  class Animal {
    constructor(name, speed) {
      this.speed = speed;
      this.name = name;
    }

    run(speed = 0) {
      this.speed += speed;
      console.log(`${this.name} runs with speed ${this.speed}.`);
    }

    static compare(animalA, animalB) {
      console.log(animalA.speed - animalB.speed);
    }
  }

  class Rabbit extends Animal {
    hide() {
      console.log(`${this.name} hides!`);
    }
  }

  let rabbits = [
    new Rabbit("White Rabbit", 5),
    new Rabbit("Black Rabbit", 10)
  ];
```

```
  console.log(Rabbit.__proto__ === Animal); // true (not problem)

  console.log(Animal.__proto__ === Function.prototype); // true (not problem)

  console.log(Rabbit.__proto__ === Animal.prototype); //(not problem)
  console.log(Rabbit.__proto__.prototype === Animal.prototype); //(not problem)
  
  console.log(rabbits[1].__proto__ === Animal.prototype); 
  // this problem
  // rabbit(name:'White Rabbit') ---[[prototype]]---> Rabbit.prototype ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**rabbits** is an object of **Rabbit**, not of **Animal**(directly)
So rabbits's **proto** will point to Rabbit's proto, and Rabbit's proto will point to Animal's proto

check this

```
rabbits[1].__proto__ === Rabbit.prototype
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `rabbits[1]` is an instance of `Rabbit` - therefore, its prototype points to `Rabbit`, but since `Rabbit` is an extension of `Animal`, `Rabbit.prototype` points to `Animal.prototype`:

```js
class Animal {
  constructor(name, speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
    this.name = name;
  }

  run(speed = 0) {
    this.speed += speed;
    console.log(`${this.name} runs with speed ${this.speed}.`);
  }

  static compare(animalA, animalB) {
    console.log(animalA.speed - animalB.speed);
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  hide() {
    console.log(`${this.name} hides!`);
  }
}

let rabbits = [
  new Rabbit("White Rabbit", 5),
  new Rabbit("Black Rabbit", 10)
];

console.log(rabbits[1].constructor.name);
console.log(Rabbit.__proto__);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object [rabbit] of Rabbit class it gets the Rabbit.prototype as its [[Prototype]] property. and rabbit.**proto** (which is [[Prototype]]) gets the Animamal.prototype property. So This is how rabbit inherits its ancestor's properties.

```
rabbit[1]<--(Inherits from Rabbbit which is rabbit[1].__proto__) <-- (Inherits from Animal rabbit[1].__proto__.__proto__)
```